# WCF aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" raise an exception (failed to load)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session

I need to have sessions enables in my WCF service.
so I have to:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

When I do that I get an exception:

> The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET
>   compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application.
>   Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the
>   AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with
>   RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'

This is my web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ExecutionEngine.AccountsBehavior" name="WebService.Services.Accounts">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WebService.Services.IAccounts" bindingConfiguration="SafeServiceConf">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>



<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ExecutionEngine.AccountsBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication
             userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
             customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WebService.Services.Security.CustomValidator,WebService" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>



<bindings>





  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SafeServiceConf" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="65536"
         maxBytesPerRead="65536" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="CrmServiceEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="CrmServiceEndpointSSL" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>

</bindings>


<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to enable session and access to it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding the following atribute to your service class?

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

You can then use the HttpContext to access the Session like this:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks! This was my first post on stackoverflow :) I'll do it next time!